# How would you represent this XML in an object?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization

```
<FileTransferSettings>
  <UploadPath src="user">C:\uploads</UploadPath>
  <DownloadPath src="app">C:\downloads</DownloadPath>
</FileTransferSettings>
```

I'd want to deserialize this XML into a FileTransferSettings object with 2 properties - UploadPath and DownloadPath.  But I also want to preserve the `src` attribute  for each property in a way that my code can interrogate it.

I think creating an associated UploadPathSrc and DownloadPathSrc property is a bit awkward and cumbersome.

Is there another way to represent this in .NET?  To me, the `src` attribute seems like it should be treated as metadata.  Is there a best practice for this?

(For background into *why* I'm trying to do this - see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578218/serialize-deserialize-to-from-multiple-xml-config-files)).

Thanks.

Comment: there is answer posted on your previous questions regarding to src attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a second class, FileTransferPath which had a string value "Path" and an enum value "Source"

```
class FileTransferSettings
{
   public FileTransferPath UploadPath { get; set; }
   public FileTransferPath DownloadPath { get; set; }
   // ...
}

class FileTransferPath
{
   public string Path { get; set; }
   public FileTransferSource Source { get; set}

   public enum FileTransferSource
   {
     None,
     User,
     Application,
     // ...
   }
}
```

Then you could use code like

```
   obj.UploadPath.Path;
   obj.UploadPath.Source;
```

There might be better names you could choose for the class properties; I don't know that I like the repetition of Path.  `obj.Upload.Path` or something might be nicer.

Note that you wouldn't be able to directly serialize/deserialize this directly to and from the format you have using XmlSerialization; but it does accomplish what you need.  (And you can still serialize to XML, you just have to do a little more work)

Comment: I think I'll end up going w/ this approach. The only issue I see with this is that if a section has 20 settings and they don't all fit into FileTransferPath, I could end up with class explosion.  Thank you though, this will work.

Comment: @vg1890: Well, depending on your needs, you _could_ include some sort of serializable dictionary equivalent (key/value pairs) to store additional information.

Answer (score 4):

In order to serialize and deserialize the XML correctly, you need to decorate the class with XML serialization attribute

```
[XmlRoot("FileTransferSettings")]
public class FileTransferSettings
{
   [XmlElement("DownloadPath")]
   public DownloadPath DownloadPath { get; set; }
   // ...
}

[XmlType("DownloadPath")]
public class DownloadPath
{ 
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string Src; // or use enum etc
  [XmlText]
  public string Text;
}

// the serialized XML looks like
<FileTransferSettings>
   <DownloadPath Src="...">text</DownloadPath>
   ....
</FileTransferSettings>
```

Comment: Nice, +1 for the XML serialization

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the general idea from Daniel L.

```
public Class FileTransferPath
{
  public Enum SourceEnum { User, App }

  public SourceEnum Source { get; set; }  //Automatic properties in 3.5 Syntax
  public string FilePath { get; set; }
}

public Class FileTransferSettings
{
  public FileTransferPath UploadPath { get; set; }
  public FileTransferPath DownLoadPath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to make the SourceEnum type public?